# Access left join on inner join

Tags: mysql, join

I want to see everything in Table `a` that has non-relation to table `c`

`a.id = b.Fid b.id = c.FID`

So I wanted to do `a` left join `a & b` on `a` inner join `b & c`;

That does not work here

```
SELECT A.ID,

FROM 
A

LEft JOIN
(B
INNER JOIN 
C
ON
C.ID =B.FID) 
ON
B.ID = A.FID

where 
C.id is null
```

Comment: Send your schema and some sample data.

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Your goal (not bug) seems likely to be a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. We cannot reason, communicate or search unless we make the effort to (re-re-re-)write clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This could work in a supposed three-tables relationship :

```
SELECT a.* FROM table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id
WHERE a.id NOT IN (SELECT c.id FROM table3 c)
```

But honestly, if you don't post any schema, it's impossible to make a real solution.

Edit: This works if the result you want is all rows **related with table2** but not with table3

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
SELECT A.Id
FROM A
WHERE (((A.Id) Not In (SELECT b.Id FROM b INNER JOIN c ON b.FID = c.Id)));
```

[Sample data and resultset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkWtx.png)

BR,  Caglar